# What is horizontal offset in iOS (UILabel)?

Tags: ios, position, uilabel, distance, offset

I'm following a tutorial that had us set a UILabel to be aligned horizontally in the container (center horizontally) and set the offset by 40. The instructor then set the trailing top space distance to the nearest UILabel above it. At first, I thought the offset was another way of setting the trailing top space distance, but I must be wrong. I was wondering what it exactly does?

Comment: The offset pertains to the horizontal constraint?  I.e., the label's center is 40 points to the left of its' container's centerline?